# Find the characteristic exponents for the given system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

> Consider the linear system
>   $$x_1'=-\nu x_1 + a(t) x_1, ~~~~x_2'=-\nu x_2 + k a(t) x_1,$$
>   where $a(t+T)=a(t)$ for all $t$ and $\nu$ and $k$ are positive constants.

Find the characteristic exponents and show that there is a periodic solution of period $T$ if and only if $\int_{0}^{T} a(t)~dt=\nu T.$

My approach: Writing the system in the form $x'(t)=A(t)x(t),$ with 
\begin{bmatrix}
-v+a(t) & 0 \\
k a(t) & -v
\end{bmatrix}

Let $X(t)$ be the fundamental matrix solution of the given system (so $X(0)=E,$ the Identity matrix). i.e.,
$$X'(t)=A(t)X(t).$$
Let us define a constant matrix by $X(T+t)=X(T)B$ for all $t.$ Then by the choice of $X(t),~B=X(T).$ Now the characteristic multipliers, $\rho$ are the eigen values of $B.$ And the characterisitc exponents, $\mu$ are defined by $\rho=e^{\mu T}.$

I solved the two ODEs and got 
$$x_1=C e^{-\nu t} e^{\int_{0}^{t} a(s)~ds},~~~~x_2=e^{-\nu t} k a(t)C e^{\int_{0}^{t} a(s)~ds}+D,$$
where $C, D$ are arbitrary constants. I'm stuck here. Any help in continuing from here on ward and completing the problem is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is clear to you that if $$\int_{0}^{T} a(t)\,dt=\nu T,$$ then there is a periodic solution, right? (Simply compute $x(t+T)$ and use this identity.)

For the other direction, write the condition $x(t+T)=x(t)$ already using your solution and simplify. For example, the first equation gives
$$
e^{-\nu (t+T)} e^{\int_{0}^{t+T} a(s)\,ds}=e^{-\nu t} e^{\int_{0}^{t} a(s)\,ds},
$$
which is the same as
$$
e^{-\nu T} e^{\int_{t}^{t+T} a(s)\,ds}= 1.
$$
Now use the fact that $a$ is $T$-periodic.

Comment: At first I was wondering whether my solutions are correct. Thank you for your help.