# Linear system of ODEs with periodic $a(t)=a(t+T) \, \, \forall t$. Periodic Solution iff $\int_0^T a(t)dt = vT$ for $v>0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> A two-species population model is described by the following linear system
>   \begin{align*}
> x_1' &= -vx_1 + a(t)x_1, \\
> x_2' &= -vx_2 + ka(t)x_1, 
> \end{align*}
>   where $a(t+T)=a(t)$ for all $t$ and $v$ and $k$ are positive constants. Find the characteristic exponents and show that there is a periodic solution of period $T$ if and only if $$\int_0^T a(t)dt = vT.$$

First we'll solve 
\begin{align*} x_1' = -vx_1 + a(t)x_1 &\iff x_1 = C_1e^{\int_0^t -v + a(\xi)d\xi} \end{align*}
for some $C\in\mathbb{R}$.
Then, through some calculation choosing to omit, we find that:
\begin{align*} x_2 = C_1e^{-tv}\int_0^t ka(z)e^{\int_0^z (a(\xi)-v)d\xi+vz}dz + C_2e^{-tv}\end{align*}
Then, my fundamental matrix $X(t)$ is
$$X(t)=\begin{bmatrix} e^{\int_0^t -v + a(\xi)d\xi} & 0 \\ e^{-tv}\int_0^t ka(z)e^{\int_0^z (a(\xi)-v)d\xi+vz}dz & e^{-tv} \end{bmatrix}$$
Then, I am unsure how to find the characteristic exponents from this matrix. I think its the eigenvalues of $B$ where $B=X(T)X^{-1}(0)$. Then, I'm not sure how the proof would even go once I find the characteristic exponents either.

Comment: So you know what meaning matrix $B$ has? It's a monodromy matrix, a matrix for a mapping over a period. If you have a periodic solution that starts at some $x_0$, what $Bx_0$ equals? What does it tell about eigenvalues of matrix $B$? Also note that $B$ is a lower-triangular matrix and its eigenvalues are just diagonal elements.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2076055/find-the-characteristic-exponents-for-the-given-system